# How to remove dynamically created imageview from another button onclick?

Tags: java, android

I have created an `ImageView` dynamically like below image.It works fine. Now I want to remove view when top cross `ImageView` is clicked. When I click, it crashes .Please help how to achieve it.
[image]

here is what i have done

```
 private void postImage(List<Uri> urilist) {
    for(int i=0; i< urilist.size(); i++) {
        imgView = new ImageView(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 150);
        lp.setMargins(20,10,20,10);
        imgView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        imgView.setId(i);
        Log.d("uri list in loop",""+urilist.get(0));
        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(urilist.get(i))
                .into(imgView);
        layout.addView(imgView);

        imgView1 = new ImageView(getActivity());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        lp1.setMargins(0,5,1,80);
        imgView1.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        imgView1.setId(i);
        Log.d("uri list in loop",""+urilist.get(0));
        Glide.with(getActivity())
                .load(R.drawable.ic_action_cross)
                .into(imgView1);

        layout.addView(imgView1);



    }

    imgView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            layout.removeViewAt(v.getId());
        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Would have been way easier if you used a RecyclerView.

Comment: whats your crash?

Comment: RemoveViewAt wants an index from you. But you give an id. So, you can try find your view with for loop, then delete with your id. By the way, you are using the wrong id. Because the view you click is cross button, not the image view you want to remove.

Comment: Can you share the crash error at the question because I think that `v.getId()` it is not working as excepted.

Comment: here is crush     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.unFocus(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Comment: @AytekSökmen would please explain with code ?

Answer (score 2):

If it is because of the index (which definitely will crash in deletion of the 2nd item) then you can try below

```
imgView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        parentView.removeView(v);
    }
});
```

Note: You should not set id of two views as same. Rather use some mathematical formula.

Answer (score 0):

I mean @shakac, you can try like that;

```
for(int i = 0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++)
{
      if (layout.getChildAt(i).getId() == v.getId()){
          layout.removeView(layout.getChildAt(i));
          break;
      }
}
```

But as I said on the comment, you will remove the cross button like that.

Comment: it only remove first item :( other item don't remove

Comment: Can you change the "..setId(i)" parts with " ViewCompat.generateViewId() " code?

Comment: it works, but from right side.if i want to remove random,suppose 2nd imageview not work and if work then cross don't remove :(